# Undefined symbol error in a shared library loaded at runtime

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

(I know various iterations of this question are asked here routinely but I didn't find anything that helped)

I'm trying to write a simple dynamic library and load it at runtime.

The library files:

`mul.h`

```
int mul(int a, int b);
```

`mul.cpp`

```
#include "mul.h"

int mul(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

Then I have this `Makefile`:

```
mul.cpp: mul.h

mul_lib: mul.cpp
    g++ -Wall -fPIC -shared $< -o bin/libmul.so

bin/test.o: mul_lib
    g++ test.cpp -ldl -o bin/test
```

So I have created an `.so` file, and I checked using `nm` that there's a symbol for `mul`... or rather what I assume is the symbol for `mul`:

```
>nm -D bin/libmul.so 
                 w __cxa_finalize
                 w __gmon_start__
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
00000000000010f9 T _Z3mulii
```

In `test.cpp`, I'm trying to load this library with `dlopen`:

```
    typedef int (*mul_func)(int a, int b);

    void* mul_lib = dlopen("bin/libmul.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if (!mul_lib) {
        /* fail to load the library */
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", dlerror()); // we don't exit here, library loaded
        return 2;
    }
    mul_func* func = (mul_func*)dlsym(mul_lib, "mul");
    if (!func) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", dlerror()); // we exit here
        return 2;
    }
    (*func)(2, 4);
    dlclose(mul_lib);
```

But I'm getting `bin/libmul.so: undefined symbol: mul`
I don't understand why. The symbol is present in the object file, it seems, and it's loaded correctly (I assume), so why is the symbol absent?

Comment: The symbol present is `Z3mulii` not `mul`. You forgot `extern "C"`, which (among other things) inhibits [*name mangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Answer (score 2):

Turns out declaring a function like this works:

```
extern "C" int mul(int a, int b);
```

For more information on why, see this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66866588/undefined-symbol-error-in-a-shared-library-loaded-at-runtime?noredirect=1#comment118198358_66866588).